# How to print from for loop to aspx page on website in asp.net Webform

Tags: c#

This is my code it is working fine it is showing me the required output at the Debug i just want to print it on the aspx page i have used TextBox.Text but its not working

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < notes.Count; i++)
{
    if (noteCounter[i] != 0)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(notes[i].Col2 + " : " + noteCounter[i]);
    }
}
```

notes and notesCounter are array not coming from the database so i cannot use Datatable here

Comment: Try to concat your output in loop as one string. And set it to the TextBox.Text. Now you are not setting text at all.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
string strtext = "";    
for (int i = 0; i < notes.Count; i++)
{
    if (noteCounter[i] != 0)
    {
        strtext=strtext+notes[i].Col2 + " : "+ noteCounter[i];
    }
}

txtbox.Text = strtext;
```

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Add.TextBox3' WebApplication1 C:\Users\asadi\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Add.aspx.cs 169 Active